# Remove Storm templates from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, apache-storm

Whenever I create a new file in Visual Studio 2015 and select "Visual C# Items" a bunch of Storm templates are at the top of the list of the items that I can add. I will never use these and they just get in the way. Is there any way to remove these from Visual Studio?

Comment: Did you tag this correctly? How is it related to Apache Storm?

Comment: The templates are for Apache Storm. It's a Visual Studio question but someone who does Storm development in VS may know the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was just able to successfully kill these by uninstalling some irrelevant (to the work I do) extensions using the Tools -> Extensions and Updates dialog box.

The "Storm" project items came from the pre-installed extension **Microsoft Azure HDInsight Tools for Visual Studio**.  Luckily that tool has an uninstall option enabled in the GUI.

[image]

In addition to removing a lot of project item templates, you'll also lose the "HDInsights" item which invaded solution explorer right-click menus, even on desktop projects with no Azure connection whatsoever.